# Does a body shaped like a cone travel faster through water than a double cone?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I read somewhere recently that a cone weightd so that it falls with point forward through water, falls faster than a double cone, of the same mass.

Is this true, and if so, why?

Comment: Is the double cone also falling ''point first"? And is geometry of each cone in the double cone the same geometry as the single cone? (So then the double cone will be less dense than the single cone to keep the masses the same)

Comment: By "double cone," do you mean one that is pointed front & back?

Comment: In any question involving fluid dynamics, you need to specify what conditions you are interested in. It's not uncommon for a configuration to be better than another sometimes, & worse other times.

Comment: @D Halsey: Yes, it's is pointed back and front. Its not a question in fluid dynamics, its merely the closest approach to what I had in mind. I'm thinking of simple experiments like Newton envisaged: like his bucket experiment. One would not call that an experiment in fluid dynamics either.